# Database connection broken even with with SQLAlchemy pre-ping

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy

Since I moved my database from a mssql docker container to an azure database as a service my web application( flask) is being disconnected after several minutes.

It is simply solved by a refresh of the page but still, there is an issue here.

The error raised by SQLAlchemy is an Operational Error (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#error-e3q8)

I tried to implement the `pool_pre_ping=True` option in the `create_engine` function the error is not solved.

I think the disconnect is initiated by the database but I do not know if there is an option to change that. (database is SQL Server 12.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy there are configuration parameters to recycle the pool.

I solved my problem by removing the `create_engine` function.

I simply add `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 300` to my configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue before. I solved it by `pool_recycle` option of `create_engine` function.

The database has default connection maintain time itself. When the connection is not used during certain period (DB setting), then DB close that connection.

So, You need set `pool_recycle` time lower then db connection maintain time.

Example,

```py
create_engine("...", pool_recycle=3600, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

Check [document](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle) for more infomation

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working working for me even with a `pool_recycle` time lower than one minute.

Comment: Uhm… did you check ‘wait-time’ of your DataBase setting? Not engine connection of python

Comment: Hope this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885946/timeouts-in-azure-sql-database

Comment: The `pool_recycle` of the create engine is not supposed to create a new connection with the database to avoid the timeout if there is no queries for more than 30min?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, well. but I think there are two closing way of connection. One is `create_engine of sqlalchemy in python`. Another is DBMS connection pool(?). So you should consider each settings. Example, db setting is 30*60(s), then you should set `pool_recycle` option **less than** 30*60(s).

Comment: the code I am using is : `engine = create_engine(app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"], pool_recycle=60, pool_pre_ping=True)` which is far less than 30min.